# Add class to selected li

Tags: jquery

I have a `ul li` like this

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="/en/products/">Search Database</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/en/what-is-nano/">Menu</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/en/report-product/">Product</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/en/news/">News</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/en/analyse/">Analyse</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/en/login/?o=login">Login</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I need to add Clicked `li` to a class. How can I do this using `jquery`. Can anyone help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You realize that clicking the anchors redirects to another page, and setting classes with javascript on the current page won't really have any effect unless you prevent the anchors from redirecting ?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
$('li').click(function(){
 $(this).addClass('active');
 $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
 return false;
});
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EGZu3/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$("li").click(function() {
$(this).toggleClass( "highlight" );
});


.highlight {
 background: yellow;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CrG5v/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.addClass()` to achieve your need.

Try,

```
$(".nav li").click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('yourClass');
});
```

Additionally if you want to switch those classes with other li elements, just try the following code,

```
var xElement = $(".nav li");

xElement .click(function(){
  xElement.removeClass();
  $(this).addClass('yourClass');
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/CrG5v/1/)